# Can I combine fuzzy and proximity searches in Apache Lucene's standard syntax?

Tags: search, lucene, proximity, fuzzy-search, opengrok

I am searching a codebase indexed by [OpenGrok](http://opengrok.github.io/OpenGrok/), the -a option has been enabled to allow the first character of a search term to be a wildcard. I would like to find all occurrences of method `foo` that take some string parameter (`foo("")` with one or more characters in the string) and the method is within 5 words of variable `bar`.

---

With the breakup of words provided by the standard tokenizer I can use `+full:"foo bar"~5` to get all `foo(` near `bar`, but excluding the parameterless methods is a problem because `("` is indexed as two whitespace characters, so for example `foo("jar")` *seems to* match `foo AND \ \ AND jar AND \ \"`. The [syntax](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_1/queryparsersyntax.html) doesn't look like it supports a search for this combination (even without the wildcard string rather than `"jar"`) with a `""~5` proximity search. Any ideas on how to achieve all or part of this, given that changing the tokenizer is not an option at the moment?

Comment: are you only able to construct queries as a query string and not programmatically?

Comment: did you ever get an answer to this @MilesHampson?